# Получение ответа на POST-запрос в NodeJs

Tags: node.js, request, websokets

Нужно реализовать нечто вроде авторизации в чате на вебсокетах. У каждого клиента есть свой токен. При подключении клиент сообщает имя и токен, а nodejs отправляет на php-скрипт запрос на проверку наличия в БД связки ник+токен. Если в БД отсутствует, разрыв соединения.

Вот только ответ (`body`) не приходит. Вместо него в консоле Chrome "`Binary frame (opcode 2)`".

Что я делаю не так?

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const url = require('url');
var request = require('request');
var port = process.env.PORT || 9030;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: port });

wss.on('connection', function(ws, req) {
 var nickName = "ExampleUser";
 var userToken = "ExampleToken";
 var serverToken = "ExampleToken";
 if (!nickName || !userToken)
     ws.terminate();

 request.post({
     url: "https://example.com/auth.php",
     headers: {"User-Agent": "example",
               "content-type": "application/ json"},
     json: true,
     body: JSON.stringify({serverToken: token, userToken: userToken, username: nickName})},
     function (error, response, body) {
         if (!body || response.statusCode !== 200 || error) {
           ws.terminate();
         }
         ws.send(body); // для отладки
         var response = JSON.parse(body);
         if (response["auth"] == "false")
             ws.terminate();
   });

ws.nickName = nickName;
ws.isAlive = true;
...
```

Код php (упрощённый):

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-stire, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_POST["serverToken"]) && $_POST["serverToken"] == "ExampleToken") {
    $response = ["auth" => "true"];
else
    $response = ["auth" => "false"];
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: может это php его не отправляет?

Comment: @Дмытрык нет, отправляет. Такое ощущение, что напутал я что-то с заголовками (application/json) или форматом запроса (json?). То ли мои параметры как-то не так передаются, то ли ответ сервера в каком-то другом режиме. Что-то же он, кажется, вернуть пытается, ибо какой-то `Binary frame` вместо содержимого `Body`.

Comment: ответ выведите в консоле терминала, а не в Хроме... так надежнее будет